# Image is not draggable (Jquery)

Tags: jquery, draggable

I´m trying to make a website using an image as a map, and have the links spread out like the markers in Google maps. I have made my image draggable using Jquery but it goes out of bounds.

I want the user to be able to pan the image and zoom in or out without scroll bars showing up. The image has to stay within a certain limit but not indefinitely like it is happening now.

Using the containment option didn´t work because this stop the drag.

Here´s my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Projecto Aurora</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-  scale=1.0"> 
      <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
      <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="aurora.css">
<script>
$(function() {
$( "#draggable" ).draggable({ 
});
}); 
</script>
</head>
<body> 
    <div id="draggable">
    <img id="bg" src="imagens/Projecto-Aurora.jpg" alt="">        
 </div>  
</body>
</html>`
```

Answer (score 0):

I would really consider [using this plugin](http://e-smartdev.com/#!jsPluginList/panAndZoomJQuery) but if you want to do it yourself
here is a demo of the draggable with containment:

### [Demo](http://jsbin.com/qicogo/edit?html,css,output)

```
$( "#draggable" ).draggable({
   containment: "parent",
});
```

Comment: miro, thanks for the answer, it is what i was looking for. The next step is to put content inside the image, like a marker of a Google map and when the user presses it, it shows a video in full screen (also i will try to show a thumbnail running the video when the user hover the mouse on the marker)...how do i fix markers in a determined place of the image? Mind you that the image is a map of Lisbon, not the aicraft project ;)